# Base change make the rational components separated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is a step in the Proposition IV.1.3 in J. Kollar's book "Rational Curves on A-V":

> [Q] Fix a field $k$ and let $\mathrm{Univ}_W\to W$ with geometric generic fiber is a curve with $m\geq 1$ rational components, then there is a generically finite morphism $Z\to W$ such that $\mathrm{Univ}_W\times_WZ$ is birational to $\coprod_m\mathbb{P}^1\times Z$. Here $W$ is irreducible.

I have no idea about this problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Choose a finite field extension $k(W) \to L$ over which the components of the generic fibre become separated and birational to $\coprod_m \mathbf P^1$ (not a Severi–Brauer twist thereof), and let $Z$ be the integral closure of $W$ in $L$. On some dense open $U \subseteq Z$, the fibres are again birational to $\coprod_m \mathbf P^1 \times U$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you very much!